# How to add Array of one entity while creating table in Oracle 11g Express Edition?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to create a table in my data base with object `publisher`
defined as

```
create type publisher as object
(  pname varchar(20),
   branch varchar(20)
)
```

and then a `book` object as

```
create type book as object(
title varchar(20),
pub_date date,
publisher publisher array[3],
keywordset varchar(20) multiset
)
```

and finally a table from book object as

```
create table Books of book
```

But, I am getting an error while creating object of `book` as follows

> Error at line 4: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ARRAY" when
>   expecting one of the following:
>
> := . ( ) , @ % not null range default external character
>
> 2. title varchar(20),
> 3. pub_date date,
> 4. publisher publisher array[3],
> 5. keywordset varchar(20) multiset
> 6. )

Please help me resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an array sub type before using it. It should be outside the object. and i don't know why you are using `MULTISET` in their.

You can create equivalent table using following code.

```
 create type publisher as object
    (  pname varchar(20),
       branch varchar(20)
    )

    create type t_publisher as  varray(3) of publisher

    create type book as object(
    title varchar(20),
    pub_date date,
    publishr t_publisher,
    keywordset varchar(20)
    )


    create table Books of book
```